How can i use the fill tool in order to not fill the layer underneath?
I need the square in the image to be filled in and to block the layer underneath any idea how to?


Try moving the Fill/Colors layer above the Lines layer and it should block out the line-art. Layers higher up in the Layer Summary hierarchy tend to hide the strokes that are in the lower layers.
